# Как сделать такой блок?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такой блок адаптивным, размер блока с текстом оставался прежним, а блок с изображением обрезался. (Фото 2)
[image: Block]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 200px 50px 0;
}
.block__img-wrap {
  margin-top: -150px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="block__img-wrap">
    <img src="https://www.nature.com/news/2017/170628/thumbs/homepage546585a-i1.0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum sunt non saepe dolores, modi maxime eum est laborum. Doloremque laudantium unde aliquam expedita quibusdam mollitia impedit doloribus eaque labore atque.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Какой такой?   Что именно не получается?

Comment: Картинку посадите на background с cover кажется, и будет вам счастье

Comment: @air, не получается правильно разместить изображение. Что бы при уменьшении размеров окна картинка обрезалась.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать фоновое изображение

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

.block {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #F9FDFF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("http://www.fastservice-ptz.ru/resources/i6787-image-original-a6e78c.png") no-repeat 60vw center;
  background-size:100%;
}

.text {
  flex-basis:350px;
  padding: 40px;
}
.text h1 {
  color: #2C3D4D;
}
.text p {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2C3D4D;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <div class="text">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>
         Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, nostrum pariatur! Est quisquam dicta at temporibus ut numquam fugiat, nisi cum placeat voluptas? Quasi, commodi facere illum excepturi mollitia corporis.
      </p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Расматривал вариант фона, но проблема в том, что на макете картинка выходит за пределы родительского блока.

Comment: Сделать отдельный блок для цвета или использовать градиент

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 200px 50px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.block p {
 width: 200px;
}
.block__img-wrap {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -150px;
 float: right;
 left: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum sunt non saepe dolores, modi         maxime eum est laborum. Doloremque laudantium unde aliquam expedita quibusdam mollitia impedit           doloribus eaque labore atque.
   </p>
   <div class="block__img-wrap">
    <img src="https://www.nature.com/news/2017/170628/thumbs/homepage546585a-i1.0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```